# Removing background and measuring features of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to measure the areas of each particle shown in this image:

[image]

I managed to get the general shape of each particle using MSER shown here:

[image]

but I'm having trouble removing the background. I tried using MATLAB's imfill, but it doesn't fill all the particles because some are cut off at the edges. Any tips on how to get rid of the background or find the areas of the particles some other way?
Cheers.

Edit: This is what `imfill` looks like:

[image]

Edit 2: Here is the code used to get the outline. I used [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/mser.html) for the MSER.

```
%Compute region seeds and elliptial frames.
%MinDiversity = how similar to its parent MSER the region is
%MaxVariation = stability of the region
%BrightOnDark is used as the  void is primarily dark. It also prevents dark
%patches in the void being detected.
[r,f] = vl_mser(I,'MinDiversity',0.7,...
                'MaxVariation',0.2,...
                'Delta',10,...
                'BrightOnDark',1,'DarkOnBright',0) ;

%Plot region frames, but not used right now
%f = vl_ertr(f) ;
%vl_plotframe(f) ;

%Plot MSERs
M = zeros(size(I)) ; %M = no of overlapping extremal regions

for x=r'
 s = vl_erfill(I,x) ;
 M(s) = M(s) + 1;
end

%Display region boundaries
figure(1) ;
clf ; imagesc(I) ; hold on ; axis equal off; colormap gray ;

%Create contour plot using the values
%0:max(M(:))+.5 is the no of contour levels. Only level 0 is needed so 
%[0 0] is used.

[c,h]=contour(M,[0 0]) ;;
set(h,'color','r','linewidth',1) ;

%Retrieve the image data from the contour image
f = getframe;
I2 = f.cdata;

%Convert the image into binary; the red outlines are while while the rest
%is black.
I2 = all(bsxfun(@eq,I2,reshape([255 0 0],[1 1 3])),3);
I2 = imcrop(I2,[20 1 395 343]);

imshow(~I2);
```

Comment: If you dilate and erode you will fill the gep between black lines and will be able to fill possibly. This will smoothen out your boundaries thought. Additionally, remember that imfill fills vlack areas to white, not viceversa

Comment: I tried eroding and dilating , it doesn't work for some of the particles, and they dont get completely filled.

Comment: Have you  tried dilating more? I am not sure, but it can be because the other particles are not "closed", as they are clipped by the edge of the image. Try this: create an image with +2 rows and cols extra form the original , adn fill those 4 lines with white pixels. Then try imfill.

Comment: Now that I think it more, that may fill your whole image. You should try somehow to "close" those particles.

Comment: Yeah I tried both white and black borders, both didnt seem to work. Closing them would be a solution, but I cant figure out how to close the particles at the edges without connecting the void between them. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the code that got you the general shape image output?

Comment: Okay, I added it to my post.

Comment: An approach that may work or not, but maybe worth to try: Create an  algorithm that goes through your boundary and split it into conected secctions (i.e. split a section whenever a 1-0-1 happens). Then, locate the largest section and assign that to "non-particle". Now supposing there is no particle just touching the border with a pixel, go labeling the rest of the secctions binarily: so if you started with 0 (non-particle) next is 1-0-1-0-1-0 till the end.  This MAY work, spetially if you dilate-erode before doing it. but its not going to work for all the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proposed solution / trick and code

It seems you can work with `M` here. One trick that you can employ here would be to pad zeros all across the boundaries of the image `M` and then fill its holes. This would take care of filling the blobs that were touching the boundaries before, as now there won't be any blob touching the boundaries because of the zeros padding.

Thus, after you have `M`, you can add this code -

```
%// Get a binary version of M
M_bw = im2bw(M);

%// Pad zeros all across the grayscale image
padlen = 2; %// length of zeros padding
M_pad = padarray(M_bw,[padlen padlen],0);

%// Fill the holes
M_pad_filled = imfill(M_pad,'holes');

%// Get the background mask after the holes are gone
background_mask = ~M_pad_filled(padlen+1:end-padlen,padlen+1:end-padlen);

%// Overlay the background mask on the original image to show that you have
%// a working background mask for use
I(background_mask) = 0;
figure,imshow(I)
```

### Results

Input image -

[image]

Foreground mask (this would be `~background_mask`) -

[image]

Output image -

[image]